# C# Validation of Period

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, validation

I want to ask if anyone knows how to limit the period allowed for a textbox. I'm using C# Visual Studio 2010.

My problem is I need to find validation codes that will ensure that only a single period is allowed for the textbox Middle Initial of the user. And if the user type another period, then the period will not be shown in the textbox. No error messages is needed. Example is the validation code that accept letters only. Here is my code for this example:

```
private void txtFirstName_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            byte num = Convert.ToByte(e.KeyChar);

        if ((num >= 65 && num <= 90) || (num >= 97 && num <= 122) || (num == 8) || (num == 32))
        {

        }

        else if (num == 13)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            SendKeys.Send("{Tab}");
        }
        else
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }

    }
```

I have the following codes currently for my txtboxMI:

```
private void txtMI_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    byte num = Convert.ToByte(e.KeyChar);

    if ((num >= 65 && num <= 90) || (num >= 97 && num <= 122) || (num == 8) || (num == 32))
    {

    }
    else if (num == 13)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        SendKeys.Send("{Tab}");
    }
    else
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add what problem do *you* have, not what task you need to complete. Side note: no need for thank you notes, signatures, first-time-here and alike as such phrases usually don't add information to the question. Also note that "homework" is obsolete tag - try  to phrase your question so it is generally useful rather than limited to just your homework.

Comment: char has many relevant methods like `IsLetter`, `IsDigit`,check them out and revisit your code

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to make it server-side?

You can use [regular expression validator](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/control_regularexpvalidator.asp).

[a-zA-Z_-.] should give you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var txt = (TextBox)sender;
if ((e.KeyChar >= 'A' && e.KeyChar <= 'Z') || (e.KeyChar >= 'a' && e.KeyChar <= 'z') || e.KeyChar == 8 || e.KeyChar == 32) {
} else if (txt.Text.Contains('.') && e.KeyChar == '.') {
    e.Handled = true;
} else if (e.KeyChar == '\t') {
    e.Handled = true;
    SendKeys.Send("{Tab}");
}
```